# Transferir archivos de sub-carpeta a carpeta principal en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo bastantes carpetas que a su vez estas tienen sus respectivas sub-carpetas, dentro de una de esas sub-carpetas hay una ***subcarpeta_1_2, subcarpeta_2_2, subcarpeta_3_2*** que contiene archivos por ejemplo:

```
 carpeta
    │── Subcarpeta_Principal1
    │   │──Subcarpeta_1_1
    │   │   │── Subcarpeta_1_2
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │── Subcarpeta_Principal2
    │   │──Subcarpeta_2_1
    │   │   │── Subcarpeta_2_2
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │── Subcarpeta_Principal3
    │   │──Subcarpeta_3_1
    │   │   │── Subcarpeta_3_2
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
```

Y lo que deseo saber es si es posible mover esos archivos a sus respectivas subcarpetas: ***Subcarpeta_Principal1, Subcarpeta_Principal2, Subcarpeta_Principal3***, así como se muestra en el ejemplo:

```
 carpeta
    │── Subcarpeta_Principal1
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │──Subcarpeta_1_1
    │   │   │── Subcarpeta_1_2
    │── Subcarpeta_Principal2
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │──Subcarpeta_2_1
    │   │   │── Subcarpeta_2_2
    │── Subcarpeta_Principal3
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │   │   │──Archivo.txt
    │   │──Subcarpeta_3_1
    │   │   │── Subcarpeta_3_2
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?.

Comment: ¿Cuando te refieres a la subcarpeta principal te refieres a la que está en el primer nivel?, uno podría pensar que la principal es la que está mas arriba y en ese caso sería `carpeta`.

Comment: @Armando le quité el resaltado de sintaxis porque no hay código involucrado pero eliminaste la edición. Fue por error?

Comment: @CésarBustíos creo que no planteé bien la pregunta, no me referia a la principal si no a las que le siguen. Refiriendome a _Subcarpeta_Principal1, Subcarpeta_Principal2, Subcarpeta_Principal3_ ..

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz me encontraba editando al mismo tiempo que tu

Comment: No hay problema ya lo edité de nuevo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos a necesitar unos imports :

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, isdir
from shutil import move
```

Obtengamos una lista de carpetas ubicadas en una carpeta base :

```
carpetaBase='/home/test/py/t'
carpetas = [ c for c in listdir(carpetaBase) if isdir(join(carpetaBase,c)) ]
```

Esas carpetas son las carpetas principales a las que queremos mover todos los archivos que se encuentren en sus subcarpetas.
Para cada carpeta principal obtengamos una lista de las subcarpetas que están contenidas inmediatamente en ellas.

```
for c in carpetas:
  carpeta = join(carpetaBase, c)
  subCarpetas = [ sc for sc in listdir(carpeta) if isdir(join(carpeta,sc)) ]
```

Para cada una de esas subCarpetas queremos mover los ficheros en ellas contenidas a su carpeta principal :

```
  for sc in subCarpetas:
    subCarpeta = join( carpeta, sc )
    moverFicherosEnSubcarpetas( subCarpeta, carpeta )
```

Ahora nos falta definir `moverFicherosEnSubcarpetas`, que debe mover los ficheros contenidos en la carpeta del primer parámetro a la carpeta del segundo parámetro.

```
def moverFicherosEnSubcarpetas( carpeta, destino ):
  # Mover ficheros
  ficheros = [ f for f in listdir(carpeta) if isfile(join(carpeta,f)) ]
  for f in ficheros:
    move( join(carpeta,f), destino)
```

Y con esto casi está todo hecho. Pero falta una cosa. Hasta ahora hemos movido los ficheros de las subcarpetas a sus carpetas principales. Pero, ¿y los ficheros de las subcarpetas de las subcarpetas? ¿Y los de las subcarpetas de las subcarpetas de las subcarpetas?, etc...

Estos podemos moverlos llamado a `moverFicherosEnSubcarpetas` recursivamente :

```
  carpetas = [ c for c in listdir(carpeta) if isdir(join(carpeta,c)) ]
  for c in carpetas:
    moverFicherosEnSubcarpetas( join(carpeta,c) , destino)
```

El código en conjunto queda :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, isdir
from shutil import move

def moverFicherosEnSubcarpetas( carpeta, destino ):
  # Mover ficheros
  ficheros = [ f for f in listdir(carpeta) if isfile(join(carpeta,f)) ]
  for f in ficheros:
    move( join(carpeta,f), destino)
  # Llamar recursivamente a subcarpetas
  carpetas = [ c for c in listdir(carpeta) if isdir(join(carpeta,c)) ]
  for c in carpetas:
    moverFicherosEnSubcarpetas( join(carpeta,c) , destino)

carpetaBase='/home/test/py/t'
carpetas = [ c for c in listdir(carpetaBase) if isdir(join(carpetaBase,c)) ]
for c in carpetas:
  carpeta = join(carpetaBase, c)
  subCarpetas = [ sc for sc in listdir(carpeta) if isdir(join(carpeta,sc)) ]
  for sc in subCarpetas:
    subCarpeta = join( carpeta, sc )
    moverFicherosEnSubcarpetas( subCarpeta, carpeta )
```